# Disable LiveEdit-like functionality for javascript in IDEA

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA for developing a ReactJS app. I start the process using Ideas' Run configuration (`npm` configuration with `start` argument).

There is some LiveEdit-like functionality in IDEA that instantly publishes all the changes I do. This would be convenient for small sites, however it drives me crazy in my case.

Every time I edit some code, even just one letter, IDEA recompiles everything, and then the app in the browser refreshes (very painful when debugging). What is worse, the app is complex (hundreds of components) and is written in TypeScript. Thus, every such operation significantly slows down the computer for about 15 seconds (mostly the type check, I guess).

All in all, it is sometimes impossible to edit JS in IDEA on my laptop, even with double-core i7 processor, because on each edit, it gets lagged.

I have tried disabling IDEA's Live Edit functionality (described here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/live-editing.html), and tried searching for many queries like *disable IDEA Live edit*, *disable instant publishing of javascript in IDEA*, *IDEA javascript disable page refresh upon code edit* and similar, but haven't found the solution.

Please, please, any idea how this IDEA's function is named? And how to make it run only manually, or on file save, and not after every edit?

Comment: `npm start` is what causes this; it's not a feature of IDEA (but `react-scripts`). Just don't call `npm start`, use `npm build` instead to create a build after your edits, then serve the folder using a web server of your choice to test the app (or just let the server run and refresh the browser after each build) *However*: afaik, a live rebuild happens after a file is *saved* as opposed to edited. You've probably trained yourself to hit Ctrl+S after each minor change (exactly what I do). Just don't save. Do your edits, then pick "Save All" from the File menu to live reload the changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the IDE feature, it's hot reloading provided by `react-scripts`. See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2519 for some hints on turning it off.

However, hot reloading only works on saving, and IDEA doesn't normally save all your files on every key press. If it only happens while debugging your app, check if **Live Edit** (that is active during debug session) is installed and enabled in **Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Live Edit** - it auto-saves files to provide live reload. Some other plugins can also be responsible for auto-saving - for example, third-party [SonarLint](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973-sonarlint) and [ESLint](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7494-eslint) plugins are known for causing such issues, as they save files to run analysis on the changes, etc.
If the Typescript language service is enabled in **Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**, make sure that **Recompile on changes** is off. And, finally, check **Build project automatically** option value in in **Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler** - it can also affect auto-saving

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the precious hints on where to look, they gave me new ideas.

I checked all the settings suggested by @lena, just to discover all of them were already off, while my problem persisted.

After further research, I found the solution. It turned out it was IDEA doing autosave afterall. In **Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Synchronization**,  I unchecked **Synchronize files on frame or editor tab activation** and **Save files on frame deactivation**.

Now the app is recompiled and republished only upon explicitely saving the file, as desired.

---

Note: If you disable autosave as described above, I recommend also enabling **Editor | General | Editor Tabs | Mark modified (*)** to keep track of unsaved files.

Comment: you should have mentioned that reloading only occurs of changing focus - the solution would be evident then

Comment: I should have, sorry for that - but I had no idea. Frankly, until now I did not even know that IDEA did something every time i switch to another window and back (alt + tab). This is a behavior I would not have expected at first.